# two $\sigma$-finite measures are mutually singular or mutually absoultely continuous if and only if such a condition is satisfied

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu, \nu$ are $\sigma$-finite measures.

(1) Prove that $\mu \perp \nu$ if and only if $\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \mu}{\mathrm{d}(\mu+\nu)}=0$.

(2) Denote $\mu \simeq \nu$ if $\mu \ll \nu, \nu \ll \mu$. Prove that $\mu \simeq \nu$ is equivalent to $\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}, \frac{\mathrm{d} \mu}{\mathrm{d}(\mu+\nu)}>$
0.

I can prove the sufficiency of (2) as follows:
Since $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu+\mu$, by Radon-Nikodym theorem:

$$
\nu(E)=\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)=\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}\mathrm{d}\nu+\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
Suppose $\nu(E)=0$, we get $\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}\mathrm{d}\mu=0$ holds. But $\frac{\mathrm{d} \nu}{\mathrm{d}(\nu+\mu)}>0$ we must have $\mu(E)=0$. Therefore $\mu \ll \nu$. Similarly, $\nu \ll \mu$.

But I don't know how to deal with (1) and the necessary part in (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are non-zero measures.

(1)  If $\mu \perp \nu$ then there exists $E$ such that $\mu (E^{c})=0$ and $\nu (E)=0$. Let $f=\frac {d \mu} {d(\mu+\nu)}$ and  $g=\frac {d \nu} {d(\mu+\nu)}$. Then $\int_E gd(\mu+\nu)=0$ and    $\int_{E^{c}} fd(\mu+\nu)=0$. It follows that $f=0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$] on $E^{c}$ and $g=0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$] on $E$. Hence, $fg=0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$], as required.
Conversely, if $fg=0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$] the check that $\mu$ is concentrated on $\{f\neq 0\}$ and $\nu$ is concentrated on $\{g\neq 0\}$. Conclude that $\mu \perp \nu$.

For the necessary part of (2), note that $\nu(E)=0$ implies $g=0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$]on $E$, But $g>0$ a.e. [$\mu+\nu$] so this forces $(\mu+\nu )(E)$ to be $0$. This also gives $\mu (E)=0$. Thus, $\mu << \nu$. Similarly, $\nu << \mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your incisive answer.